# How to use Room Persistence Library with pre-populated database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-room-prepackageddatabase

I'd like to use Room with a pre-populated database, but I can't understand how to tell Room where to find my database.

I've now put it in `src/main/assets/databases` and when I create the instance for the Room database I create it this way:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
    getApplicationContext(),
    AppDatabase.class,
    "justintrain.db"
)
.allowMainThreadQueries()
.build();
```

This way tho, I think it's creating a new database every time, or anyways, it's not using the pre-populated one.

How can I make it to find my database?

Comment: I haven't seen a good solution for this. I filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62185732) for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare so it'll take a while until it will be implemented I guess.. do you know any workaround that could be used until then? (Thanks a lot anyway for reporting it!)

Comment: Well, you could assume that the database is being stored in `getDatabasePath()` for your chosen database filename. Then, arrange to copy the asset into that path before creating the `RoomDatabase`, if that file does not already exist. This is the first option I propose in that issue, where ideally we have more assurances that "`getDatabasePath()` for your chosen database filename" is the right answer.

Comment: @AlbertoGiunta does this work for you https://medium.com/google-developers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929 ?

Comment: have you tried passing the full path of the database in the constructor? this used to work with SqliteOpenHelper

Comment: CommonsWare has a good solution here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.6/General/AssetRoom

Comment: I found this helpful https://www.meekcode.com/blog/basic-mvvm-in-android-kotlin-using-prepopulated-database-and-room-with-unit-testing-part-1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is how I solved it, and how you can ship your application with a pre-populated database (up to Room v. alpha5)

- put your SQLite DB `database_name.db` into the `assets/databases` folder
- take the files [from this repo](https://github.com/albertogiunta/sqliteAsset) and put them in a package called i.e. `sqlAsset`
- in your `AppDatabase` class, modify your Room's DB creation code accordingly:

  ```
  Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                       AppDatabase.class, 
                       "database_name.db")
  .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
  .allowMainThreadQueries()
  .build();
  ```

Note that you have to use `"database_name.db"` and not `getDatabasePath()` or other methods: it just needs the name of the file.

Comment: Hey Alberto, what program would you recommend for the .db file generation (I mean, database editor)? I need an editor that generates a database compatible with the Room schema.

Comment: Hei @PedroGuerra! I used a really simple program named "DB Browser for SQLite". I think it's crossplatform so that should work well for your needs!

Comment: Works also with alpha9 (only need to implement method from `AutoClosable` where needed) but unable to do it with beta1 (`SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration` missing some stuff so `AssetSQLiteOpenHelper` cannot be instantiated)

Comment: @AlbertoGiunta Hey Alberto, sorry for the request, but could you please create a new tag on github, so I can use jitpack to import it into my project?

Comment: Hi, i can't use it in .kt

Comment: Thank for @Alberto Giunta
It saves my time!

I using your code and build to dependency to easy for use in here! 
https://github.com/daolq3012/AssetSQLiteOpenHelper

Anyone can use this by easy way.

Comment: Thank you @AlbertoGiunta, this solution still works on recent version of the Room library.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to write migrations when updating the database schema using this prepopulated DB? Upon updating the schema, the database is always empty

Comment: i need like something prepopulated database which i downloaded from google drive api and use it

Comment: It's request Java 8?

Comment: @young_boy; Is there a way to override the existing database when increasing the database version?

Comment: As I saw the issues on GitHub on both repos(didn't test it myself), the problem remains on updating the database it seems.

Answer (score 33):

**UPDATE** (Nov 7th 2019)

Room now supports using a pre-packaged database out of the box, since version 2.2.0

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0

**Solution before version 2.2.0: Simple solution without any other external libraries.**

Room relies on the existing Android framework code to create or open a database. If you look into the source code of `FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper` (Room's version of `SQLiteOpenHelper`) it internally calls `SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()` and other methods wherever needed.

So, the simplest solution is to just copy the DB file from assets directory to `mContext.getDatabasePath("my-database.sqlite")` before creating the DB with Room.

In your case, the code looks something like this -

```
private final String DB_NAME = "my-database.sqlite";

private MyDatabase buildDatabase(Context context) {
    final File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);

    if(!dbFile.exists()) {
        copyDatabaseFile(dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    return Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        MyDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
        .build();
}

private void copyDatabaseFile(String destinationPath) {
    // code to copy the file from assets/database directory to destinationPath
}
```

This link has the code needed to copy the DB - [link with code](https://android.jlelse.eu/room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database-5f17ef103d3d)

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be the accepted answer. I've spend a whole day trying to figure this out. I knew we do not need another library and that copying database file to database location should work.

Comment: Unfortunate that this answer is only 3rd place and probably missed by many.

Comment: How would you write a test for that?

Comment: How do you tell Room to use the newly copied database? I can confirm through a file browser that the db is transferred correctly but Room.databasebuilder still generates an empty db.

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same problem so I created a library which does exactly that.
the accepted answer work but I think it's easier to use a library.

```
AppDatabase db = RoomAsset
    .databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database_name.db")
    .build();
```

Add it to your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.github.humazed:RoomAsset:v1.0'
}
```

you can find the library here: https://github.com/humazed/RoomAsset

Comment: This is risky. Migration may not be successful.

Comment: can you elaborate what mean risky!. is there any certain concern.

Comment: I personally use `Context.deleteDatabase()` in Application when the application upgraded.

Comment: It's not working: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.

Answer (score 16):

## **Working 2019 solution without hacks or dependencies (Kotlin)**

1. Place your `.db` file in `assets/databases` (or really any folder in there, as long as it's under `assets`).
2. Use Room 2.2's existing `createFromAsset()` function, passing in the path to the database. For example, if your database file is named `my_data.db` and is under the `databases` directory of the `assets` folder, then you would do `createFromAsset("databases/my_data.db")`.

Assuming your database name (e.g., `my_data`) is stored in a constant variable named `DATABASE_NAME`, you can use this sample code:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                )
                    .createFromAsset("databases/$DATABASE_NAME.db")
                    .build()
```

**Important**: Make sure the schema of your data class/entity precisely matches the schema of your `.db` file. For example, if a column isn't explicitly marked as `NOT NULL` in the `.db` file, then that means the column can have null 
values in it. In Kotlin, you would have to match that with `val colName: dataType? = null` in your data class. If you just do `val colName: dataType`, Kotlin will compile that to a `NOT NULL` column, and that will throw an exception when you try to run your app.

**Note**: If instead you want to create a Room database from a database file that you download onto the Android device itself, you can alternatively use the `createFromFile()` function. Check out the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createFromFile(java.io.File)) on how to do this.

Comment: But won't this override the database in the phone on every startup? How to check if the db already exists?

Answer (score 12):

Room now supports **Prepopulated Databases**. Just prepare your database by using a program like [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) or any other of your choice. Then put it in `Assets Folder` probably in a subfolder called `database` then call:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
.createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
.build()
```

If you did not provide your database as an Asset but you downloaded it or it is  in File System then then the method is:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
.createFromFile(File("mypath"))
.build()
```

For more description or database migrations about this Feature you can check the [Documentation Training](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).

Comment: Works Perfect. A Huge Thanks to @Xenolion You saved my many days.

Comment: I just noticed, my Database is always being overridden by the one inside assets (every time I launch the app). Didnt anyone else had this issue? Using Room 2.2.5

Comment: I know it, click here lets see if i can help you, text me there and delete your comment  and i will delete mine https://wa.me/255684521543

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution with room without using external libraries:
1. Copy your database in assets folder 
2. Copy your database from assets folder

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static AppDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    copyDatabase(getApplicationContext(), "yourdatabase.db");

    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), .class, "yourdatabase.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}

private void copyDatabase(Context context, String databaseName) {
    final File dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName);

    // If the database already exists, return
    if (dbPath.exists()) {
        Log.d("Activity", "db Path Exists");
        return;
    }

    // Make sure we have a path to the file
    dbPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    // Try to copy database file
    try {
        final InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(databaseName);
        final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dbPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int length;

        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Activity", "Failed to open file", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Room 2.2, you can pre-populate your database using command below:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, TestDatabase.class, “Sample.db”)
    .createFromAsset(“database/myapp.db”)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

you just copy `assets/databases` to `app/databases`
and than add `addMigrations()` in `databaseBuilder`
it will keep your data