# Why is there no database file created when using Android Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I use the Room Persistence Library for my Android app, but after it's creation I can not find .sql file with tables on my device.

When I create database through `SQLiteOpenHelper` I can see all my tables in folder *data* on the device, but when I create database through Room there is no file anywhere.

Where can I see the content of all my tables?

Create database code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
PokuponDataBase providePokuponDataBase() {
    return Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(SuperDealApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), PokuponDataBase.class, "PokuponRoomDatabase").build();
}
```

Comment: Try `getDatabasePath()` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263891/how-to-use-room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database#comment75538553_44263891).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the cause of disappearing my database. It was because I create it incorrectly. I use Room.InMemoryDatabaseBuilder() instead of simple Room.databaseBuilder() and after each application reloading my db was recreated and also inMemory database does not create any files.

Comment: Posting the code snippet in the question could have saved your time ;)

Comment: @WorieN pls, accept your own answer as "the answer"