# Where Room save database Android?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am using Room library to save data in database.i want to get database.

used this code

```
  private void copyFile() {

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath=getDatabasePath("photex_db.db").getAbsolutePath();
                String backupDBPath = "photex_db.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

it works in simple sqlLite but **did not work for ROOM Library [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)**

is there any way can get Database?

Class to create DataBase with help of Room

```
  @Database(entities = {ProjectDataEntity.class, SavedProjectEntity.class},
        version = 2)
     @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)

     public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

     static final String DATABASE_NAME = "photex_db";

     private static AppDatabase Instance;

     public abstract ProjectDataDao projectDataDao();

     public abstract SavedProjectDao savedProjectDao();

     public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (Instance == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (Instance == null) {
                    Instance = 
      Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return Instance;
    }


}
```

Comment: "it works in simple sqlLite" -- not on many devices or for many users. **Never hardcode paths**. [Use `getDatabasePath()`, please](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)). "did not work for ROOM Library" -- if you use `getDatabasePath()`, it should work with Room. If you encounter problems, provide a [mcve], which would include the `RoomDatabase` where you are providing the information to Room about what database to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare  i tried getDatabasePath() it does not help :(

Comment: Then, as I wrote, please provide a [mcve], which would include the `RoomDatabase` where you are providing the information to Room about what database to use.

Comment: I updated the question ,see if it is this you mean

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925671/why-is-there-no-database-file-created-when-using-android-room) answer. Maybe you just create database incorrectly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "photex_db";
```

Here, you are trying to open `photoex_db`.

```
String currentDBPath=getDatabasePath("photex_db.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

Here, you are trying to read from `photex_db.db`.

These are not the same.

You might consider using `DATABASE_NAME` consistently, rather than only in some places.

Comment: Where should I call `getDatabasePath()`. I mean which class provides it?

Comment: @MayurRokade: `getDatabasePath()` is a method on `Context`.

Answer (score 15):

in Android Studio there is a section called "Device File Explorer", at the bottom right. In this section you can explore all the files
(which you can not see in a simple file explorer app because you need to run the root).

Make sure the emulator is the one you're working with.
In this explorer you have to go to "data" -> "data", look for the package name of your app and the next step is to find "database" entry, in this folder there is your Room database.

Answer (score 5):

There was a little mistake in my code ,after correcting its working fine

```
private void copyFile() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath =
                    getDatabasePath("photex_db").getAbsolutePath();
            String backupDBPath = "photex_db.db";
            //previous wrong  code  
            // **File currentDB = new File(data,currentDBPath);**
            // correct code
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: getDatabasePath("photex_db") returns file object, File currentDB = getDatabasePath("photex_db") for simplicity

Comment: To Get the Room database storage path using SupportSQLiteOpenHelper refer link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069135/5453198

Answer (score 3):

Try out this code :

```
String backupDBPath = YourRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context).getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().getPath();
```

It will return the path of your database. Use this exact path to create the file where you want to copy it. It will definitely work as worked for me.

```
File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) `getDatabasePath Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created with openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) is stored.` In case of Room it is not working

Comment: Just wanted to note that I am using Room (2.3.0) and getDatabasePath() is working correctly for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
//kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "appData.sqlite")
    .addMigrations(
        MIGRATION_1_2,
        MIGRATION_2_3
    )
    .build()
    .also {
        Log.d("<DEV>", it.openHelper.writableDatabase.path)
    }
```

focus on                             it.openHelper.writableDatabase.path
where "it" is your db object inherited from RoomDatabase