# Android room database won't export all the data

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-sql

I'm trying to setup Room database backup functionality. 
Problem is that sql database file doesn't contain latest set of data in the app once downloaded. It always misses some most recent records. 
Is there a proper way to export room database? 
P.S. I didn't face similar problems when handled my db with sqliteHelper, so I suppose it must have something to do with Room.

Way I'm doing it:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copyAppDbToDownloadFolder(address: String) {
    val backupDB = File(address, "studioDb.db") 
    val currentDB = applicationContext.getDatabasePath(StudioDatabase.DB_NAME)
    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        val src = FileInputStream(currentDB).channel
        val dst = FileOutputStream(backupDB).channel
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
        src.close()
        dst.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: also update when you backup start

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986465/where-room-save-database-android hope helpful for you

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987119/backup-room-database/51560124#51560124).

Comment: you should close your database before copy it , try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976242/4858757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it. When exporting (saving) sql database which you handle with Room, you have to export(and later import) both - your_database.bd and your_database.wal files. Later is a journal and afaiu keeps latest records.

Comment: what is path of both file please explain i have same problem

Comment: @Lokesh
There are several ways to get db path. I'm using the following:

`val currentDBPath = "//data//" + packageName + "//databases//" + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME + ""
                val backupDBPath = DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME + ".db"
                val currentDB = File(data, currentDBPath)`

Comment: Another approach is this (note that I use it to get .wal file path): 

`val currentdbW = applicationContext.getDatabasePath(StudioDatabase.DB_NAME + "-wal")`

Answer (score 14):

You need to use

> JournalMode.TRUNCATE

in your AppDatabase.java:

```
private static AppDatabase sInstance;

public static AppDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                        .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

This method will not create **db.bad** and **db.wal** files that's creating hindrance in exporting room db.

***For exporting the DB file:***

> Link: [Exporting db with creating folder on daily basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android/53167018#53167018)

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue. you don't need to copy wal (write ahead log file) it's a temporary file. According to [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) we need to close all connection to database before importing or exporting database. This solved my problem and now i have to copy only main database file.

Example of database class:

```
public abstract class AppDB extends RoomDatabase {    

    private static final Object sLock = new Object();

    private static AppDB INSTANCE;

    // create new database connection
    public static AppDB getInstance(final Context context) {
        synchronized (sLock) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDB.class, "packagename")                    
                    .build();
                }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }

    // close database
    public static void destroyInstance(){
        if (INSTANCE.isOpen()) INSTANCE.close();
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great news! And how exactly do you close all the connections to the database?

Comment: just call close() function on all your room database objects.

Comment: @MuzammilHusnain "*all your room database objects*" There should only be one instance of an open database.

Comment: @rupinderjeet yes ideally there should be only one instance of an open database.

Comment: The problem is that if you reopen the database and try to execute anything, it fails, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987119/backup-room-database

Comment: The idea is really useful, you need to close the database, then the original database can be copied or backed up

Answer (score 2):

kotlin:This works for me

```
private fun exportDb() {
    val TABLE_NAME = "order_table"

    val exportDir = File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/CSV")// your path where you want save your file
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs()
    }

    val file = File(exportDir, "$TABLE_NAME.csv")


    try {
        file.createNewFile()
        val db: MenuItemsDatabase = MenuItemsDatabase.getDatabase(requireActivity())
        val csvWrite = CSVWriter(FileWriter(file))
        val curCSV: Cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM order_table", null)
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames())
        while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
            //Which column you want to exprort
               val arrStr = arrayOfNulls<String>(curCSV.getColumnCount())
        
            for (i in 0 until curCSV.getColumnCount() - 1) arrStr[i] = curCSV.getString(i)
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr)
        }
        csvWrite.close()
        curCSV.close()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Exported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } catch (sqlEx: java.lang.Exception) {
        //Log.e("Payment fragment", "Exported error", sqlEx)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Exported error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem and I solved it by copying the 3 files that are generated. I work correctly. And the same is done to import.**

```
copyDataFromOneToAnother(application.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).absolutePath, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DATABASE_NAME.db")
                    copyDataFromOneToAnother(application.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).absolutePath + "-shm", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DATABASE_NAME.db" + "-shm")
                    copyDataFromOneToAnother(application.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).absolutePath + "-wal", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DATABASE_NAME" + "-wal")
```

```
 private fun copyDataFromOneToAnother(fromPath: String, toPath: String) {
            val inStream = File(fromPath).inputStream()
            val outStream = FileOutputStream(toPath)

            inStream.use { input ->
                outStream.use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        }
```