# Android: SQLite database created with room shows no tables when opening with sqlte-browser

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, sqlite-browser, sqlite-journal-mode

I am using **Room Persistence Library 1.1.0**. I could find the database file at `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/` using Android Studio's  Device File Explorer.

It contains multiple tables and I can access contents of that tables without any problem using `room-DAO`s. However when opening with `sqlite-browser`, is shows no table.

What might be the reason? Is it possible to resolve the issue without switching back to old `SQLiteOpenHelper` from room?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Solution

To open *such databases** with `sqlite-browser`, **you need to copy all three files**. All must be in the same directory.

<sup>* Databases stored in multiple files as stated in the question.</sup>

## Why three files?

As per docs, Starting from version `1.1.0`, Room uses `write-ahead logging` as default journal mode for devices which has sufficient RAM and running on API Level 16 or higher. It was `Truncate` for all devices until this version. `write-ahead logging` has different internal structure compared to `Truncate`.

Take a look at the files temporary files used by `SQLite` now and then :

**Until version 1.1.0**

[image]

**From version 1.1.0**

[image]

If you want to change the journal mode explicitly to `Truncate`, you can do it this way. But, **it is not recommended** because `WAL` is much better compared to `Truncate`.

```
public static void initialize(Context context) {
    sAppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase.class,
            DATABASE_NAME)
        .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE).build();
}
```

## Is it possible to move it to single file without changing to `Truncate` ?

Yes, it is. Query the following statement against the database.

```
pragma wal_checkpoint(full)
```

It is discussed in detail here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51560124/7594961).

Answer (score 15):

Copy all three files from Device File Explorer in AndroidStudio to your PC directory and open the db file in Db Browser for SQLite (http://sqlitebrowser.org). Make sure all three files are in the same folder.

Comment: As an alternative there is also `sqlitestudio` https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wal_checkpoint` pragma to trigger a [checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt) which will move the WAL file transactions back into the database.

```
        theRoomDb.query("pragma wal_checkpoint(full)", null)
```

or

```
        // the result
        // contains 1 row with 3 columns
        // busy, log, checkpointed
        Cursor cursor = theRoomDb.query("pragma wal_checkpoint(full)", null)
```

See [PRAGMA Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) for more details about the pragma parameter values and results.

If the WAL is not enabled the pragma does nothing.
By the way, I tested with Room 1.1.1, and the WAL mode was not used by default, I had to enable it.

Comment: `theRoomDb.query` is not working for me without `Dao`

Answer (score -2):

**Room database Export and Import Solution**

Im facing same problem in one of my project, i spend two days to resolve this issue.

**Solution**

> Don't create multiple instance for Room library. Multiple instance creating all the problems.

**MyApplication**

```
class MyApplication: Application() 
{

companion object {
    lateinit var mInstanceDB: AppDatabase
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    mInstanceDB = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
}
}
```

**AppDatabase**

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase 
{

if (sInstance == null) {

    sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java, "database").allowMainThreadQueries().build() 

            return sInstance!!
}
}
```

Now use this instance in any number of activity or fragment just like that

```
{
    var allcustomer = MyApplication.mInstanceDB.customerDao.getAll()
}
```

Export and Import use this library

```
implementation 'com.ajts.androidmads.sqliteimpex:library:1.0.0'
```

[Github link](https://github.com/androidmads/SQLiteImporterExporter)