# How to make the data visible in DB

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I use Room for work with database. When I save data to the database, they are saved to the .db-wal file and not to the database.

**How can I make me see the data visible in the database?**

When I fill the db, I see that volume of wal file is increasing but bd - not =(. And I'd like to see data to have controll which data is saved.

[image]

[image]

Here is an example to project I used
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

Comment: I think wal file is temporary storage for your data and it will be moved to db file once you close database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wal is a temporary db file, just copy all 3 files.
If you want to merge data in the .db you need to perform a checkpoint, or disable wal.

Check this: [Android: SQLite database created with room shows no tables when opening with sqlte-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148012/android-sqlite-database-created-with-room-shows-no-tables-when-opening-with-sql)