# how to correctly backup room database

Tags: android, android-room

I read [Backup Room database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987119/backup-room-database) but I think answers contains errors for new releases of android studio and I want to know how to correctly backup and restore room database in 2022 in kotlin or java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. Database has 3 files that I have to save those files for backup:

```kotlin
val dbName = RoomDb.DATABASENAME
val documentFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) 
when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.mnuBackup -> {
        val db = getDatabasePath(dbName).absolutePath
        val wal = getDatabasePath("$dbName-wal").absolutePath
        val shm = getDatabasePath("$dbName-shm").absolutePath
        File(db).copyTo(File(documentFolder, "$dbName"), true)
        File(wal).copyTo(File(documentFolder, "$dbName-wal"), true)
        File(shm).copyTo(File(documentFolder, "$dbName-shm"), true)
    }
    R.id.mnuRestore -> {
        val dbExternal = "$documentFolder/$dbName"
        val walExternal = "$documentFolder/$dbName-wal"
        val shmExternal = "$documentFolder/$dbName-shm"

        val db = getDatabasePath("$dbName").absolutePath
        val wal = getDatabasePath("$dbName-wal").absolutePath
        val shm = getDatabasePath("$dbName-shm").absolutePath
        File(dbExternal).copyTo(File(db), true)
        File(walExternal).copyTo(File(wal), true)
        File(shmExternal).copyTo(File(shm), true)
    }
    else -> {

    }
}
```