# RoomDB file location

Tags: android, database, android-room

I for the first time use RoomDB in my project. I have the next question: where does the database file store, after i created the next ?

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            AppDatabase.class, "database")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
```

P.S. Don`t pay attention on my mistakes.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask where is the database file stored?

Comment: @BradenBrown I mean the location on phone storage or somewhere else in memory or in ram

Answer (score 0):

> where does the database file store, after i created the next ?

```
Log.d("DB", "DB_Path: " + context.getDatabasePath("database"));

OutPut:
DB_Path: /data/user/0/{app.package.name}/databases/database
```

Comment: If it must be in my phone storage, it doesn't.

Comment: Check [CommonWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012643/1283715)