# Open SQLite database with specified path with Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to access a databse on an Android's internal storage by specifying its path using the Room library. So far, I have been doing it by using the following statement:

```
dbPath = "/data/data/my.sqlitetesting/files/database/myDataBase.db";
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

How do I acces this DB with Room?

Comment: AFAIK you have to implement custom `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` and `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory` then use `RoomDatabase.Builder.openHelperFactory` .... `AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").openHelperFactory(customFactory)build();`

Comment: First, put Room aside for a bit. Never hardcode paths. That hardcoded value is wrong for many Android devices, based on OS version or user (e.g., secondary accounts). Your hardcoded value maps, more or less, to `new File(new File(getFilesDir(), "database"), "myDataBase.db"))`. But then I agree with Selvin; because you have your database in a non-standard location, AFAIK you will need a custom `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` that can derive the proper location at runtime.

Comment: '@CommonsWare You are right and i haven't actualy harcode it, I just wanted to show what such a path might look like.

Comment: But, how are we going implement `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper`? As, we need to return `SupportSQLiteDatabase`. Implement `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` interface, is not same as extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` (which is an abstract class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, import db file to room is currently not OK. But there is another way: [How to use Room Persistence Library with pre-populated database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263891/how-to-use-room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database)

You can try also this library: [RoomAsset](https://github.com/humazed/RoomAsset)

Answer (score -2):

@Jan Malek I use this code to know if I have SD Card and get the path NO SD CARD 
I then get the path for internal storage

```
    public void onAvail() {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable) + "/Documents/";

        //System.out.println("ALL TRUE ==> " + THE_PATH);

    } else {// if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        THE_PATH = "";
        //System.out.println("ALL FALSE ==> "+ THE_PATH);
    }
}
```

Try these few lines of code I believe your path is incorrect in the code you posted if this does not work please advise us

```
        Context context = this;
    String removable = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable)+"/";
    System.out.println("INTERNAL PATH ======> "+THE_PATH);
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "NAME_OF_FILE");
    String PA = String.valueOf(file);
    System.out.println("Where AM  I ======> "+PA);
```

Comment: @janmalek I do not mind a down vote that said you accepted the answer and by clicking the up button would seem logical to me but I have two down votes and do not understand WHY can anyone explain

Comment: Your response did not answer my question. I was asking how to connect to an SQLite database with Room library. I was not asking how to aquire the path of such database.