# Fetching pre-populated data from ROOM database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am new to android development. I am creating an app with room persistent library. I already have a pre-populated .db file. I am able to insert and fetch my own data but I am not able to fetch already existing data from the database.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Room doesn't support pre-populated data by default.

but I created [this library](https://github.com/humazed/RoomAsset) which helps you to use a pre-populated database from assets folder.

and you can use it like this

```
final AppDatabase db = RoomAsset.databaseBuilder(
                getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "your_db_name.db").build();
```

see [the sample](https://github.com/humazed/RoomAsset/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/huma/roomforasset/JavaActivity.java#L23:20) for example.

see [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263891/how-to-use-room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database/47372887) for more alternatives