# How to access files within your project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to access a database file from my project. I have created an assets folder in my project and added the file to the folder.

How do I get the url of the database so that I can use it with the jetbrains form like this:

```
Database.connect("jdbc:h2:file:~$path/testDB", driver = "org.h2.Driver")
```

**Here is the Screenshot of the file:**

[image]

Comment: There is no URL to that database. You will need to copy it to a file on the filesystem (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`) and then use that. Also note that using JDBC on Android is very unusual.

Comment: It might be unusual, but I can not change the database, unless I copy it into another database type.

Comment: "unless I copy it into another database type" -- the native database for Android is SQLite. You can convert your database to SQLite and package that with your app. You will find **much** better support for SQLite on Android than you will find for JDBC.

Comment: you can also use room database library for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263891/how-to-use-room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database . Might be little advanced if you are a beginer.

Comment: but how do I copy it to the filesystem. I come form the iOS world, so sorry if I ask stupid questions.